# How to I get two variables from Firebase Realtime DB

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

in my app I want to get two Integer Variables from my database
[My Realtime database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pp8eY.png)

I want to get 'gedrueckt' from 'text_1'. But I'm always struggling with very complicated guide(my english is not the best and more or less new to java) and something that I don't get to work because the app crashes...

I tried this at last, but I'm not shure if it would get the correct things from my database and how I would get it to work because of crashing.

MainActivity.java :

```
        myRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            String text = "text_" + selecter;
            Log.d(TNOT, dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class));

        }
```

Error while using the code up there:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                     Process: com.example.alex.wouldyoupressthebutton, PID: 22850
                                                                                     com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String
                                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdzl.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdzl.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                         at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
                                                                                         at com.example.alex.wouldyoupressthebutton.MainActivity$1.onChildAdded(MainActivity.java:99)
                                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdqc.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdvo.zzbur(Unknown Source)
                                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdvu.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6316)
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
```

Hope you can help me with this problem.

MrMinemeet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to read values like Key-Pairs.

```
  for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    String yourText = String.valueOf(data.child("name from your fierbase child ").getValue());
    yourObjectList.add(yourTextValue);
  }
```

or  one complete example :

```
private DatabaseReference mDataBaseRef;
mDataBaseRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()

ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    int youtItemId = dataSnapshot.child("user").child("yourItemId").getValue(Integer.class);
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    // Log the message from databaseError
  }
};

mDataBaseRef.addValueEventListener(postListener);
```

And Another example :

```
DatabaseReference reference = 
database.getReference("UserInfo").child("gameStats");
reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    // You have to use key-value pairs like in ContentValues
    // To loop through the values

    for (DataSnapshot snap: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
     snap.child("child") yourObeject.getValue(youObject.Class) 

    }

}
```

}